# Dynamic variable created in function not available in future calls

Tags: bash

I have a script that is (supposed to be) assigning a dynamic variable name (s1, s2, s3, ...) to a directory path:

```
savedir() {
    declare -i n=1
    sn=s$n
    while test "${!sn}" != ""; do
        n=$n+1
        sn=s$n
    done
    declare $sn=$PWD
    echo "SAVED ($sn): ${!sn}"
}
```

The idea is that the user is in a directory they'd like to recall later on and can save it to a shell variable by typing 'savedir'.  It -does- in fact write out the echo statement successfully:  if I'm in the directory /home/mrjones and type 'savedir', the script returns:
    SAVED (s1): /home/mrjones

...and I can further type:

> echo $sn

and the script returns:
    s1

...but typing either...

```
> echo $s1
```

...or

> echo ${!sn}

...both return nothing (empty strings). What I want, in case it's not obvious, is this:

> echo $s1

```
/home/mrjones
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  [apologies for the formatting...]

Comment: Forgot to mention that I also tried:  export $sn   ...and:  export $sn=${!sn}

Comment: Are you aware of the directory stack in `bash`? `DIRSTACK` already exists; just use `pushd` instead of `cd` to populate it.

Comment: Thanks @chepner - I'm aware of the stack, but I wasn't sure it would be useful for this.  I need to be able to reference the directory in bash commands (e.g., mv, cp, etc.).  For ex.  mv $s1/somefile.txt $s3/.   But I might not be fully appreciating what DIRSTACK is for - will check out. Thanks again!

Comment: Even if you just want a list of arbitrary directory names, use an array instead of dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a variable using a name stored in another variable I use `printf -v`, in this example:

```
printf -v "$sn" '%s' "$PWD"
```

`declare` here is creating a variable local to the function, which doesn't seem to be what you want.  Quoting from `help declare`:

> When used in a function, `declare` makes NAMEs local, as with the `local`
>       command.  The `-g` option suppresses this behavior.

so you can either try the `-g` or with the `printf`

Comment: FANTASTIC - I went with the declare -g option -- this works perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead.

```
savedir() {
    s+=("$PWD")
    echo "SAVED (s[$((${#s[@]}-1))]): ${s[${#s[@]}-1]}"
}
```

Comment: Oh my... that is deep.  Thanks @chepner - I will definitely give that a try!

Comment: The second line is less ugly if you just define `n=$(( ${#s[@]} - 1 ))` first. Then it is just `echo "SAVED (s[$n]): ${s[n]}"`.